# Django queryset more simpel

Tags: python, django, object, subquery, query-by-example

is there a way to combine those 2 lines of code?

```
a = terminal.provisioning_set.first()
b = a.usergroup.id
```

the result is coming from:

```
 terminal = Terminal.get_object(terminal_id, request.user)
```

I like to see something like this:

```
result = terminal.provisioning_set.first(usergroup.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

`first()` doesn't accept any arguments. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#first)

> `first()` - Returns the first object matched by the queryset, or None if there is no matching object.

So what you've shown is incorrect.

You can try like this.

```
result = terminal.provisioning_set.first().usergroup.id
```